# updating a value of a single line with multiple numeric values

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file with different number of records i want to update the value(numeric) at a particular position multiple times

For e.g 
here is file with multiple rows

254235335**63**634242423536363633

254235335**64**634242423536363633

254232335**66**634242423536363633

254235335**69**634242423536363633

254232335**70**634242423536363633

254232335**71**634242423536363633

254235335**65**634242423536363633

Now i want to update the value present in BOLD in every line only if the first five values of the line are "25423".

So if 5 line have the first five values as "25423" i want to update the value present in BOLD in every line by 1 .

Can some one suggest a way to do it

Also all the values to be update are present at fix position.i.e 10-11 as here.

Thank in advance

Comment: It'd have made sense to include some lines that DON'T start with 25423 in your sample input so when we test our potential solutions we can see if they only modify the targt lines or not. Also, edit your question to show the expected output given the input you posted. Include an example where the 2 chars are `99` so we can see if you want that to become `100` and the whole line to become 1 char longer or `00` or something else.

Comment: I would suggest writing a script for it.  Sometimes we are obsessed with doing everything in a single line, when updating and changing it causes us to go crazy.

Comment: If your goal is to add 1 to the field in question, then sed is not the right tool for the job, as it includes no concept of arithmetic.  You could do this in almost any other language though, awk, ruby, python, perl, tcl, bash/ksh/etc. It would be great to know what you've written so far.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you want 99 + 1 to become 00, not 100, and is tested against your posted input file but with `99` in the key position in the last line instead of `65`:

```
$ awk '/^25423/{$0=sprintf("%s%02d%s",substr($0,1,9),(substr($0,10,2)+1)%100,substr($0,12))} 1' file
25423533564634242423536363633
25423533565634242423536363633
25423233567634242423536363633
25423533570634242423536363633
25423233571634242423536363633
25423233572634242423536363633
25423533500634242423536363633
```

Comment: Darnit, you posted exactly the same thing as me, right after I took my eyes off the StackOverflow window!  You're TOO FAST, Ed Morton!  :-)  +1 of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's/^\(25423.\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\11/g'
```

**Test:**

```
$ echo "25423533563634242423536363633" | sed 's/^\(25423.\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\11/g'
2542353351634242423536363633
```

Comment: This always puts a 1.  It does not add 1.

Comment: hello sat and @ergonaut i have one more query this does works perfectly fine for me.But i also would like to know if i have values in between the lines on basis of which i should update how can i search for that.

Comment: In the test case shown, this changed `63` to `1` - is that what you actually wanted when you said `i want to update the value present in BOLD in every line by 1`? I (and @karakfa apparently) assumed you wanted to add 1, not replace it with 1. This is why you should always post the expected output in your question as well as the sample input, because more often than not the stated textual requirements are ambiguous.

Comment: FWIW that sed command could be a bit more concise and simple: `sed 's/^\(25423....\)../\11/'`.

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=""} /^25423/ {v=10*$10+$11+1;$11=v%10;$10=((v-$11)/10)%10}1'
```

after 99 it will be back to 00. Outputs.

```
25423533564634242423536363633
25423533565634242423536363633
25423233567634242423536363633
25423533570634242423536363633
25423233571634242423536363633
25423233572634242423536363633
25423533566634242423536363633
```

Comment: There's nothing gawk-specific about that. However, it's not entirely portable either as POSIX doesn't define the meaning of `FS=""` so not ALL awks will split the record into characters given `FS=""`.